# Get access to appsettings.json in typescript + angular 2 (.Net Core)

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, typescript2.0

I'm developing **.NET Core app + TypeScript + Angular 2**.

And I want to get access to `appsettings.json` file in angular 2 / typescript code.

Can I do this? And if yes, then how?

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. `appsettings.json` is only a part of the configuration system, it can be override by commandline args, environment variables or distributed key-value stores (i.e. azure key vault) etc. If you want share a specific setting, read it into a poco class during startup and inject it in a controller and pass it back to the client requesting it